# Broadcom BCM4311 not working

Tags: wireless

I have an Dell Vostro 1500 with a Broadcom BCM4311 wireless networking card in it, and just installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (via USB drive).  Following installation, the ethernet card/connection works great, but it doesn't seem to 'see' the wireless card.  If I go into Settings -> Network, it only shows the Wired connection, no wireless.
When I type "*lspci -vnn |grep Network*", it DOES show the BCM4311 (14e4:4311, rev. 01) so it clearly is aware of its presence.  I have taken it online and done "*apt install firmware-b43-installer*" and rebooted but still no dice.
When I type "*lspci -vnn |grep -A 9 Network*", it shows the device using the b43-pci-bridge Kernel Driver.
I'm not sure where to go from here!

*EDIT - the results of "sudo dmesg |grep b43" are as follows:
[   27.281177] b43-pci-bridge 0000:0c:00.0: Sonics Silicon Backplane found on PCI device 0000:0c:0

Results of "`grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*`" are:

/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43

/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43legacy

/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:install wl modprobe -r b43 b44 b43legacy
ssb; modprobe --ignore-install b44

/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43 and ssb.

Results of "`sudo modprobe b43 && sudo dmesg | grep b43`"are:

[   27.281177] b43-pci-bridge 0000:0c:00.0: Sonics Silicon Backplane found on PCI device 0000:0c:0

[15156.109291] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4311 WLAN found (core revision 10)

[15156.152584] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 4, Type 2 (G), Revision 8

[15156.152625] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2050, Revision 2, Version 0

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep b43` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have edited the original question to include the requested information.

Comment: May we also see: `grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*` and: `sudo modprobe b43 && sudo dmesg | grep b43`

Comment: Done.  I apologize for the bad formatting, it didn't seem to want me to keep things single-lined without my doing a double CR after each line for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your wireless doesn't start because its driver `b43` is erroneously blacklisted. Let's fix it:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is now working.

Comment: Amazing, I didn't even have to reboot - as soon as I removed the .conf file it saw the wifi card!  I am now online wireless, thank you SO MUCH for the quick and patient assistance!!!